# How to see Kernel Oops/Panic? and provide "proof"

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-panic, kernel-module

I'm doing this assignment and I'm kind of confused on providing proof for kernel oops/panic

```
static int __init hello_init(void)
{
        printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world!\n");
        return 1/0; //Crashes the program
}
```

How do I get the proof of a kernel panic? I know the use of dmesg but I can only see that in the terminal. What other ways are there to deliver a convincing proof of it?

Comment: A kernel panic will cause the Scroll Lock and Caps Lock lights on your keyboard to flash continuously; the system will stop responding. The flashing lights are designed to be a signal to visually indicate that the machine has crashed, even if you cannot view the console.

Answer (score 0):

If the kernel has panicked, the machine should be completely hung (no response to keyboard or mouse), and the **Scroll Lock** and **Caps Lock** lights should be flashing continuously. The flashing lights are intended to signal a kernel panic even you cannot view the console.